# WIX Heat, Change the name of the subdirectory through heat?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

So I am using Wix to install my application, it works great and does everything that I need.  The one issue I am having now is this.  I am using the following command line argument in my VS 2010 Pre-build Event command:

```
heat.exe dir "C:\My Main Folder" -cg MyApplication -gg -scom -sreg -sfrag -dr APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY -var var.MyApplication -out "..\..\MyApplication.wxs"
```

My issue is that the .wxs file that is generated gives me the following folder structure:

```
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY">
        <Directory Id="dirB19DCB4311BD6C765579FE56A2C72DF8" Name="My Main Folder">
```

My question is if there is a way to pass in an argument that could change the name of the "My Main Folder" directory, because as of right now I am changing it manually but this is extremely inefficant and makes it so that we cannot have an automated build process.  If anyone has any suggestions or places I could look that would be great!  Right now I am leveraging the "*WiX: A Developer's Guid to Windows Installer XML*" book to try and find a solution but am not finding anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you are aiming to do, I would be tempted to use `-srd` to suppress the generation of the root directory and then change the `-dr` parameter to point at the directory with the correct name.

Other than that, I think the only other simple option is probably an XSL transform, which you can use by specifying the `-t` parameter.

Comment: That did the trick. Never thought to suppress the generation of the root directory thanks! Also for those using the same book as I that have this problem as it turns out you can find this information on pages 52-56

Answer (score 1):

As ChrisPatrick suggested you can use the `-srd` to suppress the generation of the root directory and use your own with `-dr`.

```
heat.exe dir "C:\My Main Folder" -srd -dr "DIRNAMEHERE"
```

You can find more information here, [heat documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm)